# How to array only one key from another array

Tags: php, array, categories

I'm editing the category.php template and I need an array of current category child's.

I'm able to get an array with current category child's but there are too many keys, I'm using the following:

```
//get category ID                
$catego = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $catego->cat_ID;

//list current category childs
$catlist = get_categories(
            array(
            'child_of' => $cat_id,
            'orderby' => 'id',
            'order' => 'ASC'
) );
```

That gives me the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 11
            [name] => test1
            [slug] => test1
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 11
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 10
            [count] => 3
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 11
            [category_count] => 3
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => test1
            [category_nicename] => test1
            [category_parent] => 10
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 12
            [name] => test2
            [slug] => test2
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 12
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 10
            [count] => 1
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 12
            [category_count] => 1
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => test2
            [category_nicename] => test2
            [category_parent] => 10
        )

)
```

Now from this array I want to create an array which will only have the [cat_ID] key. I've tried the following but it gives me nothing ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php ):

```
$category_id = array_column($catlist, '[cat_ID]');
print_r($category_id);
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
// This converts the WP_Term Object to array.
$catlist = json_decode(json_encode($catlist),true);

$category_id = array_column($catlist, 'cat_ID');
print_r($category_id);
```

Comment: @Mike You're welcome .. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `array_map()`

```
$category_id = array();
$category_id = array_map( function ($data){
            return $data['cat_ID'];
        }, $catlist);
```

Or wordpress function:

```
   $category_id = array();
   $category_id =  wp_list_pluck( $catlist, 'cat_ID' );
```

Comment: +1 for `wp_list_pluck()`

Answer (score 0):

A foreach loop works:

```
$category_id = array();
foreach ($catlist as $cat){
    $category_id[] = $cat->cat_ID;
}
```

Comment: Nope, still nothing:(

Comment: How about the foreach @Mike